# heading fade out triggered on pixel point

Tags: javascript, css

So I am trying to get my heading to fade out once the user reaches a certain pixel point (say 300 down) ([

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250) {
    $("header").fadeOut();
  } else {
    $("header").fadeIn();
  }
})
```

```css
header { 
  opacity: 1;
}

header .fade { 
  opacity:  0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="fade">
    <h1>
      amateur designer and very amateur developer.
    </h1>
    </header>
```

][1](https://studioakademi.com/)), and the js I have [refuses to work](https://mine.superhi.com/) and I have no idea why! Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your CSS is interfering with jQuery's natural `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` behavior. If you remove your CSS and dump this into a fiddle, it works!

https://jsfiddle.net/768u4r3z/2/